# What are the differences between "disseminate", "propagate" and "spread"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

What are the differences  between the three words: *disseminate, propagate* and *spread*?

Here are some examples from a fill-in-the-blank test:

> 1. News is __ by means of television and radio. (disseminated)
> 2. Don't __ malicious reports. (propagate)
> 3. Some people are keen on __ rumours. (spreading)

I want to know the specific differences of the three words, and why they cannot be replaced with each other.

Comment: Is this something you have to do as part of a class assignment? If it is, the question may be closed. What efforts have you yourself made to find the answer?

Comment: I have the same concerns as @BarrieEngland. As it stands, we don't even know if you looked up the words in a dictionary.

Comment: @Cameron: I'd normally echo that sentiment as well, but, in this case, the dictionaries are of little use, as the definitions are circular. The fact that the O.P. is asking why they cannot be replaced with each other suggests that some preliminary research was performed, as there is much overlap in meaning between the words. (Still, I agree that the question could be improved by providing some dictionary definitions within the question).

Comment: Yes. This is part of class assignment. The answers are provided in the textbook, but no explanations are available. I looked up in the Oxford Dictionary of English, and the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English. Just as what JR says, the definitions are circular. I was quite confused. (Yes. I should have provided some dictionary definitions within the question. Thank your all for your concern.)

Comment: It depends on how high you're holding your pinky finger when you say it.

Answer (score 4):

For questions like this, I normally agree with Barrie's comment, but I'm having trouble figuring out why a test would ask you to differentiate between these largely synonymous words with such examples.

The words have somewhat circular definitions in dictionaries.  For example:

> **propagate**: to promulgate; disseminate [[Collins #3](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/propagate)]
>   **disseminate**:  spread or disperse (something, esp. information) widely [[Oxford](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/disseminate.aspx)]
>   **spread**: to give information to many people [[Macmillan #7](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/spread)]

*Disseminate* means *to spread*, but the implication is to spread widely among a large group of people.  Still, in the example sentence, I think the word *broadcast* would fit better than *disseminate*.

*Propagate* also means *to spread* ([Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/propagate) describes it as *to spread ideas, beliefs etc to a lot of people*), but it also carries a connotation of *passing along* information. You hear something, and, instead of keeping it to yourself, you tell someone else.

*Spread* is the most generic of the three, and the word can be used in a wide variety of other contexts (you can *spread* peanut butter on a slice of bread, for example).

Idiomatically, *spread* is often used with *rumors*, but that doesn't mean the other two words are never used.  [Here is the Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=propagate%20rumors,disseminate%20rumors,%20propagate%20rumours,%20disseminate%20rumours&year_start=1900&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) for *“propagate rumors”* vs. *“disseminate rumors”*; the expressions are found, but are dwarfed [when we add *“spread rumors”* to the Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=propagate%20rumors,disseminate%20rumors,propagate%20rumours,disseminate%20rumours,%20spread%20rumors&year_start=1900&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).  That's the main justification I can think of for using *spreading* with the third sentence; *rumors* are generally said to be *spread*.

All in all, though, I don't think the answers to sentence examples are utterly obvious, even to a native speaker, and you can find contextual examples of the words being swapped.  For example, [*reports* can be *disseminated*](https://www.google.com/#q=%22disseminate++reports%22&hl=en&tbo=d&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=E9OYULqxEdGgyAGLyoGYCw&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=2d1f0915c3c377c2&bpcl=37189454&biw=1554&bih=863), and [*news* can be *propagated*](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&spell=1&q=%22propagate+the+news%22&sa=X&ei=ZNOYUP7cJevOyAGploCQBw&ved=0CCsQBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=2d1f0915c3c377c2&bpcl=37189454&biw=1554&bih=863).

Comment: I thought disseminate means to scatter information widely as if sowing seeds, and propagate means to make members in public accept an idea and be followers. But now I know I was wrong. These two words may be interchangeable, and that rumors are generally said to be spread. Thank you very much for your thorough analysis.

Comment: @JanLiu: Careful - I wouldn't say that you were wrong. In fact, I'd say you were correct! That said, many words in English are rather flexible, and can expanded to be used in a wider, more general context than what a strict definition might indicate. That's why so many words in English have multiple definitions, and why various dictionaries offer different definitions. But the two definitions you provided are quite valid.

Comment: :I guess I've already had a much better understanding of these words with your help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -3):

Dissemination (broadcast also is good word with the same meaning depending on the context we use) is an unorganized way of just sowing seeds,generally used by free thinkers and philosophers, who do not belong to any religion, nation, caste,creed or community. This way there is urgency of this kind of reaching out public.
 Where as Propaganda that involves faiths ideology means to make members in public accept an idea and be followers. (here the urge and seeking respectability open or hidden is common which Neiztuke the philosopher stated as evil...) Here there is an element and motive behind an inevitable business mentality which is harmful and diving the world, the only reason for spreading hatred and violence, that has become threat to humanity.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but I am pretty sure that the reason someone else did is that your response consists of what appear to be a series of personal opinions without objective support. To make your answer more acceptable at this site, you would need to document the statements you make with specific references to corroborating information in appropriate reference works. You might also focus on the three verbs (_disseminate_, _propagate_, and _spread_) that the poster asks about, rather than on the two related nouns (_dissemination_ and _propaganda_) that your answer emphasizes.